# Crash Logs not Symbolicating

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

I am running Xcode 4.2.1, but none of my crash logs are symbolicating. These are crash logs from my phone for apps built on my mac. Any suggestions to fix this would be appreciated please

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you archiving the builds before deploying them? The symbolication will only work for the latest build (if I remember correctly), if you create archives, and then deploy those builds, it will automatically symbolicate those logs.

You could also save the app.DYSM files separately and manually symbolicate them.
This will give you more information on how to do this manually.

> [Symbolicating iPhone App Crash Reports](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1460892/symbolicating-iphone-app-crash-reports)

This site also provides more details on manually symbolicating crash logs

> http://kevincupp.com/2011/05/12/symbolicating-ios-crash-logs.html

Comment: Hi thanks for your reply. I dont archive all builds, just those I distribute. I thought Xcode would symbolicate all local builds.

Comment: Do you have to archive with debug mode ?, After archiving how to you send it to your iphone? Just by running it ?